# Insertar un echo dentro de div con php

Tags: php, html, div

Colegas

Necesito imprimir el resultado de completadas según el siguiente código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy súper novato en esto pues quisiera avanzar pero esto me tiene atorado

me aparece el siguiente error en consola linux

Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

por favor vuestra ayuda y sáquenme de mi ignorancia

Saludos.

---

Muchas gracias por sus repuestas pero al ingresar el siguiente codigo

[image: <?php echo $completadas\['total'\]; ?>]

considerando la consulta sql

$query="SELECT COUNT(status) as 'total' FROM call_center.calls WHERE status = 'Success'";

Me entrega el siguiente error

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /var/www/html/dash01/home.php:181\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/dash01/home.php on line 181

si vemos la linea 181 tiene lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega la clase de conexión y por favor usa código en lugar de imágenes, es mas fácil ayudar así

Comment: Disculpa había puesto  la imagen por que  marcaba de mejor manera el detalle

Comment: ¿Tu variable "completadas" de PHP es la que necesitas imprimir si valor en el marco que resaltas?

Comment: @Alan tal cual lo indicas!

Comment: Te hace falta un punto y coma en `<?php echo "completadas" ?>` ademas de que estas imprimiendo el texto **completadas** mas no el valor de la variable **$completadas**, por lo cual debería ser así `<?php echo $completadas; ?>`

Comment: "El objeto de la clase `mysqli_result` no se pudo convertir a cadena" `$completadas` es un resultado de una consulta que puede ser nulo o contener resultados, no es directamente imprimible como string ( cadena de caracteres )

Answer (score 1):

**COUNT() function** 
La función `COUNT ()` devuelve un recuento de varios valores no NULL de una expresión dada.

Si no encuentra ninguna fila coincidente, devuelve 0.

Por lo tanto, si quieres imprimir el valor en tu **HTML**, deberás poner la linea como:

```
<?php echo $completadas; ?>
```

En **PHP** para imprimir datos, en este caso dentro de tu HTML, deberás poner la palabra `echo` seguido de lo que quieres imprimir, y aquí tienes dos opciones con las que estas teniendo confusión:

1. Para imprimir una variable deberás pasar el nombre de la variable tal cual después del `echo`.

```
<?php echo $Variable; ?>
```

2. Para imprimir un texto deberás poner entre comillas dicho texto.

```
<?php echo "Texto"; ?>
```

Si ademas quieres imprimir estos dos tipos deberás concatenar cada uno de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php echo "TEXTO1 " . $Variable1 . " TEXTO2 " ?>
```

El punto (`.`) sirve para poner unir estos dos tipos en uno solo y **PHP** pueda imprimir todo como si solo de texto se tratase.

Answer (score 0):

Al ejecutar la consulta, el resultado se guarda en un array. Incluso aunque sea únicamente un valor, su formato es array. De hecho, para poder trabajar con ello lo ideal sería que tu query fuese así:

```
SELECT count(status) as 'total' FROM call_center.calls WHERE status = 'Success'
```

Hecho eso, tu resultado se mostraría así:

```
<?php echo $completadas['total']; ?>
```

Automáticamente, el resultado se guarda en un array asociativo donde los índices son los nombres de las columnas. No es necesario asignar un alias para poder llamar al array, pero sí que lo hace mucho más cómodo y limpio.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por su ayuda ya encontre el problema y era como me estaba conectando pues llamaba a ciertas clases las cuales me entorprecian  algunos metodos

Lo solucione con la siguiente linea

$count = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(status) as 'total' FROM call_center.calls WHERE status = 'Success'"));

la variable $con es el metodo de conexion (el clasico host, db, user, pass etc)

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que el resultado que quieres imprimir esta en array, tienes que extraer los registros individuales, prueba con esto.

```
<?php

$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(status) as 'total' FROM call_center.calls WHERE status = 'Success';");

while ($reg=$resultado->fetch_object()){

    echo $reg->total;

}
```

Espero te ayude.